# Is $M_\infty \simeq M_\infty \otimes M_\infty \simeq M_n \otimes M_\infty$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, category-theory, solution-verification, limits-colimits

All matrix rings are over the integers, colimits are colimits of $\mathsf{Rng}$s and $\otimes$ means $\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}$.

My guess is that yes, indeed, and my reasoning is as follows: since $M_\infty =  \mathrm{colim} M_n$, then

$$
M_\infty \otimes M_\infty \simeq \mathrm{colim}_{(i,j)} M_i \otimes M_j \simeq \mathrm{colim}_{(i,j)} M_{ij}
$$

and similarly

$$
M_n \otimes M_\infty \simeq \mathrm{colim} M_{in}.
$$

Both of these are isomorphic to $M_\infty$ if the following is correct,

> Proposition: let $f : (\Lambda,\leq) \to (\mathbb{N},\leq)$ be a cofinal order-preserving function. Then $\mathrm{colim}_{\alpha \in \Lambda} M_{f(\alpha)} \simeq M_\infty$.

*Proof.* For each $\alpha \in \Lambda$, the identity maps of $M_{f(\alpha)}$ composed with inclusion to $M_\infty$ assemble into a map

$$
\gamma : \mathrm{colim}_{\alpha \in \Lambda} M_{f(\alpha)} \to M_\infty
$$

Picking a matrix in $M_\infty$, by cofinality it is contained in some $M_{f(\alpha)}$ and so it is in the image of $\gamma$. Likewise, if an element in the colimit is given by a matrix in $M_{f(\alpha)}$, its image in $M_\infty$ coincides with the image via the monomorphism $M_{f(\alpha)} \hookrightarrow M_\infty$ and thus $\gamma$ is injective. $\square$

Is this proof correct? Is there a more categorical proof? That is, can we deduce that $\gamma$ is an iso without appealing to bijectivity? Also, there seems to be some general fact about diagrams indexed by (filtered?) posets hiding somewhere.

As a side question (which I think is a bit to narrow not to include here),

> Is the morphism $M_\infty \to M_\infty \otimes M_\infty$ given by tensoring the inclusion $\mathbb{Z}\ni k \mapsto k \cdot e_{11} \in M_\infty$ with $M_\infty$ an iso?

Comment: You mention colimits. Colimits of what exactly?

Comment: My bad, I probably should have specified. All my colimits are of $\mathsf{Rng}$s (which I think is where the equalities I stated are true). As for the "can we make this more categorical?" question, feel free to modify the context as needed.